# Is it valid to apply an operation to coordinates on a graph? Ex: $2(a,b) = (2a, 2b)$?

Tags: analytic-geometry, graphing-functions

As the title says, is it valid to do something like $2(a,b)$ where $(a,b)$ are points on a graph, such that $(a,b)$ becomes $(2a,2b)$ ? or is this not valid because coordinates cannot be changed using an operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $xy$-plane is also known as $\Bbb{R}^2$, and it forms a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$.  So the operation $\lambda (a,b) = (\lambda a, \lambda b)$ is valid *by definition* of a vector space.  Look up the definition of vector space to see.

Now if $(a,b)$ is a coordinate of a graph of a function $y = f(x), \ f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$, where by graph you mean $G(f) = \{ (a,b) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : b = f(a) \}$, then if $(a,b) \in G(f)$, then $\lambda (a,b)$ is $\notin G(f)$ possibly.  I.e. it isn't necessary that $G(f)$ is closed under scalar multiplication in $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Take for example the well-known $f(x) = x^2$.  Then $(2, 4) \in G(f)$, but $2(2, 4) \notin G(f)$.

What are necessary and sufficient conditions for $G(f)$ to be closed under scalar multiplication by some $\lambda$?  Well,

$$
\forall (a,b) \in G(f), \lambda (a,b) \in G(f)  \\
\iff
\forall a \in \Bbb{R}, f(\lambda a) = \lambda f(a)
$$

Thus the graph of all linear functions is closed under scalar multiplication by $\lambda$ for all $\lambda \in \Bbb{R}$, for example.

Comment: so then, if i wanted to create a function $\ f : \Bbb{N} \to$ P, where P stands for coordinates that are elements of Natural numbers, what is an example of a function that would work?

Comment: Any linear function $f : \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N}^k$, $f(n) = (a_1 n, \ a_2 n, \ \dots, \ a_k n)$ should work, where $a_i \in \Bbb{N}$.

Comment: sorry, I was unclear, I meant P where it stands for (a,b) coordinates on a graph, where a and b are elements of Natural Numbers

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean now and this is my fault, since I didn't ask in a comment to your OP.  But what do you mean by $\Bbb{P}$ now?  Is it $G(f)$ for some $f$, or what space is it?  When you have a function you usually have two spaces that it maps between, be it vector spaces, groups, rings, topo spaces, what have you.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. The domain is Natural numbers, that maps to the codomain of P. I just used P as a random letter to represent the set of numbers $P = \{(a,b)\mid a,b ∈ \mathbb N\}$ . So what would be a formula for a function that maps $f : \mathbb N -> P$ ? It doesn't have to do with G(f) in your explanation.

Comment: @gticecream8 Use or state $P = \Bbb{N}^2$, so people understand what you're trying to convey. The function $f : \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N}^2$ given by $f(n) = (a_1 n, a_2 n)$, satisfies: for all $c \in \Bbb{R}$, $f(cn) = c f(n)$, consequently $G(f)$ is closed under scalar multiplication by any $c \in \Bbb{R}$ because in my answer I tried to show you that that was a sufficient condition.  Prove the proposition in my answer.

Comment: ah, I see now. Thank you

Comment: @gticecream8 Note that linearity is only a sufficient condition, not a necessary one, unless you can prove that somehow, idk!